# How to open a cmd with a command a certain amount of times

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a cmd opening with a certain command and want it to duplicate the amount of times that they type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type inside the batch script `myscript.bat`:

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
    echo.%%i
)
```

This will print 1..10 numbers.

For details type inside console window: `for /?`

If you want open separate console on each iteration:

```
@echo off
for /L %%i in (1,1,10) do (
    start "" "%COMSPEC%" /C "echo.%%i&pause"
)
```

Comment: Perhaps using the `/K` option for `cmd`|`%comspec%` would be useful too!

Comment: @Compo A bit less useful, because you have to click the cross sign to close the window, when in mine example you can close a window by any key press.

Comment: Perhaps the question wasn't about opening `cmd` windows, _(my understanding)_, where I'd assume `For /L %A In (1 1 5) Do @Start Cmd /K` would open `5` of them!

Comment: @Compo As i read correctly, author wants to open cmd with `a command` inside it. It's unclear how, but i think author can reach it by yourself from the example.